# Htaccess: Rewrite Rule adding Trailing Slash in the middle of URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not really familiar with RegExp and it's really hard for me.
I want to do the following:

Rewriting this:

`http://www.example.com/pl?utm_source=test&utm_medium=testing&utm_campaign=test-testing`

to this:

`http://www.example.com/pl/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=testing&utm_campaign=test-testing`

As you can see I want to add a trailing slash after "pl".

Hope anyone has an idea. (or tutorials, guides etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GOT IT:**

It was easier than I thought:

```
   RewriteRule ^(..)$ $1/
```